# HTTP request in C++ for BlackBerry 10

Tags: c++, qt, http, get, blackberry-10

From [this webpage](https://github.com/blackberry/Cascades-Samples/tree/master/httptest), I have code.

When I use `"http://httpbin.org/get"`, everything is OK.

But when I use my own url, for example `"http://my-json-server.typicode.com/typicode/demo/db"`, I'm getting an error:

> Unable to retrieve request headers

Where is my fault?

```cpp
void RequestHeaders::getRequest()
{
    //const QUrl url("http://httpbin.org/get"); // OK
    const QUrl url("http://my-json-server.typicode.com/typicode/demo/db"); // Not OK

    QNetworkRequest request(url);

    QNetworkReply* reply = m_networkAccessManager->get(request);
    bool ok = connect(reply, SIGNAL(finished()), this, SLOT(onGetReply()));
    Q_ASSERT(ok);
    Q_UNUSED(ok);
}

void RequestHeaders::onGetReply()
{
    QNetworkReply* reply = qobject_cast<QNetworkReply*>(sender());

    QString response;
    const QByteArray buffer(reply->readAll());

    bb::data::JsonDataAccess ja;
    const QVariant jsonva = ja.loadFromBuffer(buffer);
    const QMap<QString, QVariant> jsonreply = jsonva.toMap();

    QMap<QString, QVariant>::const_iterator it = jsonreply.find("headers");
    if (it != jsonreply.end()) {

        const QMap<QString, QVariant> headers = it.value().toMap();
        for (QMap<QString, QVariant>::const_iterator hdrIter = headers.begin();
            hdrIter != headers.end(); ++hdrIter) {
            if (hdrIter.value().toString().trimmed().isEmpty())
                continue;

            response += QString::fromLatin1("%1: %2\r\n").arg(hdrIter.key(),
            hdrIter.value().toString());
        }
    }

    for (it = jsonreply.begin(); it != jsonreply.end(); it++) {
        if (it.value().toString().trimmed().isEmpty())
            continue;

        response += QString::fromLatin1("%1: %2\r\n").arg(it.key(), it.value().toString());
    }

    reply->deleteLater();

    if (response.trimmed().isEmpty()) {
        response = tr("Unable to retrieve request headers");
    }

    emit complete(response);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `onGetReply` handler is parsing the server's HTTP response body as JSON, searching it for a `"headers"` child field, and if found then extracts that child's own child fields into a local `response` variable.

`http://httpbin.org/get` responds with a JSON object containing a `"headers"` child object that has child fields in it.  So your `response` variable ends up not being empty.

`http://my-json-server.typicode.com/typicode/demo/db` responds with a JSON object that does not contain any `"headers"` child.  So your `response` variable is left empty.

You need to either:

- fix your server to respond with JSON that actually matches what your code is expecting.
- fix your `onGetReply()` code to handle the JSON that your server is actually sending.

Comment: Hello thank you for your answer.
When I try change "headers" to "posts" or "comments" or "profile", I get the same error message :(   *****QMap<QString, QVariant>::const_iterator it = jsonreply.find("posts");*****